# Curl file download using ftp protocol fail with RETR response 550

Tags: curl, ftp

I am trying to download a file from the server to specific path on client, when  I run the following curl command I am getting error:

```
  curl -u test:test "ftp://<serverip>/home/test/README.txt" -o ~/home/dccom/testserver/db/log/README.txt
 The curl command error is as follows : 
 % Total  % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 0    0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 curl: (78) RETR response: 550
```

Please suggest the if any proper format for this download

Comment: i think that is a fancy `404 /home/test/README.txt not found`

Answer (score 0):

```
 -The path format changing will work : 

curl -u test:test 'ftp://10.226.45.7/%2fhome/test/README.txt' -o /home/dccom/testserver/db/log/README.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when the permissions of the file on the ftp server were restrictive.

Using the Windows IIS FTP and I had to add the 'IUSR' in the security property tab.

On linux you will need to probably workout either if 'test' user has permission to access the file or if the ftp server has permission to access the file. Good Luck